# Multiple testing between treatment groups, and between subgroups within treatments. Bonferroni correction required?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I have a data set that is structured such that I have four treatment groups with 6 samples each; 3 samples in each treatment were taken at an early time point, and the other three were taken at a later time point. (There are actually more data than this, but this is the basic structure of the dataset).

The goal is to compare the means of a given parameter using a one-way ANOVA. The first ANOVA I ran was to compare means by treatment group, which returned a significant result. Thus, I wanted to know *which* groups are different, so I applied Tukey-Kramer as a post hoc test for pairwise between treatment groups. My plan is to adjust my critical threshold using the Bonferroni correction here (k=6 comparisons) to avoid Type I Error.

I also want to compare means between Early and Late samples for each treatment, which would result in 3 additional ANOVA tests.

My question is, do the final 3 ANOVA tests lead to a value of k=9 that I apply to all tests? Or do I apply different Bonferroni corrections to the different levels of testing?

I tried to search for a similar question on this forum but could not find one. It is possible that I am not using the right terminology, as I have not had to do testing in this way before. Please let me know if I need to clarify my question, or if there are previous posts that address this. Thank you.